# Resources and R code for analysing advanced experimental designs?

Tags: r, references, experiment-design, sas

I switched from `SAS` to `R`. I was using ["SAS Code for Some Advanced Experimental Designs"](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/library/SASExpDes_os.htm) as a reference whenever I had data from experimental design studies. With advanced experimental designs I always have difficult to come up with right `R` code. Specifically I have a tough time with mixed effects analysis. I couldn't find any comprehensive material for analyzing advance experimental designs in `R`. I'd highly appreciate if someone point out any such material. It'd be nice if someone translate these  [SAS Codes for Some Advanced Experimental Designs](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/library/SASExpDes_os.htm)  to [R Code for Some Advanced Experimental Designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15904/3903).

Comment: Interesting question. Of course, if there's a specific type of analysis that you know how to perform in SAS, but not in R, then that might make a good separate question here.

Comment: @JeromyAnglim: Thanks for your appreciation. 'Split-Plot Designs' (SPD), Split-Block (Strip-Plot) Designs (SBD) and Split-Split-Plot Design (SSPD) specifically in Mixed Model context.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ExperimentalDesign.html

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: Thanks for pointing http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/ExperimentalDesign.html. I already looked it. My question is much related to R codes. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few resources for performing various types of mixed and factorial ANOVA in R:

- http://www.personality-project.org/r/r.anova.html
- http://www.statmethods.net/stats/anova.html
- http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/04/repeated-measures-anova-with-r-tutorials/

Answer (score 3):

There is a book by John Lawson [Design and Analysis of Experiments with R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439868131)

That same author has also written a book with same title using SAS [Design and Analysis of Experiments with SAS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420060600)

This might give you a starting point!!